# Is golang caching DNS?

Tags: go, dns

I'm running a piece of golang code to resolve a url.

This url should returns one ip on 50% of the requests and another ip on the others 50%.

This is working when I perform the `host` command but not when I resolve the DNS using Go. On my research, every answer I saw they said Golang doesn't cache DNS but the behavior seems to be different.

Can anyone clarify that?

Here is my code and I'm using a for loop to run it 100 times:

`for value in {1..100};do go run main.go;done`

```
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    iprecords, _ := net.LookupIP("google.com")
    for _, ip := range iprecords {
        fmt.Println(ip)
    }
}
```

Comment: What OS are you running this on? And are your compiling with `CGO` enabled (go build default) or disabled?

Comment: I'm running on OSX and I didn't know about CGO. It was enabled. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The default resolver does not do any caching. The asked DNS resolver might do caching though. Make sure that `host` and your code actually query the same resolver.

Comment: Go on OSX, by default, uses CGO which seems to cache  DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CGO_ENABLED=1 (the `go build` default) on `OS X`, according to the [net package docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net#hdr-Name_Resolution), `Go` will use:

> ... the cgo-based resolver ... on systems that do not
> let programs make direct DNS requests (OS X)

so if you are observing DNS caching on `MacOS` - then this is happening at OS-level.

You can try using the `Go`'s native DNS resolver to see if that is a viable alternative.

You co this this by either:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build  # disabling CGO
```

or more subtly using the runtime env var:

```
export GODEBUG=netdns=go    # force pure Go resolver
```

This has its limitations, for example on VPN split-tunnel DNS routing will not work using `Go`'s native resolver. YMMV.