# How do i make go dns lookup force usage of nscd if available?

Tags: go, dns

Is there any way i can force a go binary to perform dns lookup's and get response from the nscd cache on the same host if it is available?
I assume it can be forced if i use a custom resolver, but i'd like to avoid that. Wondering if netdns=cgo would help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes but it depends on your environment.
You can use `cgo` resolver by typing to terminal

```
export GODEBUG=netdns=cgo
```

Then your go application will use cgo resolver.

cgo resolver use `getaddrinfo` when resolving domain names if your OS is UNIX.

And `getaddrinfo` will use `nscd` if `nscd` service is running.

ref.

[1] https://pkg.go.dev/net#hdr-Name_Resolution

[2] [Is golang caching DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70468536/is-golang-caching-dns)

[3] https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/golang-dns-resolving-a56ed59981fe

Comment: Do I need to set this at compile time? At runtime? Both?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I think it is for runtime. `GODEBUG` is the environment variable.
So, when the program is run, it extracts its value from the variable. You can see the code here. https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/go1.13/src/net/conf.go#293